# How to get the Excel sheet cell data by column name in using apache POI library

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to get the cell data of a particular sheet with column name rather than column index, 
Currently i can get the cell data using

```
fis = new FileInputStream(ExcelPath);
wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
sh = wb.getSheet(SheetName);
cell = sh.getRow(rownum).getCell(colnum);
```

but I am looking for a way where I can get the cell data by,

```
cell = sh.getRow(rownum).getCell(ColName); //not working
```

Comment: Do Excel columns really have names? Or do you mean the cell text in the first row of the column?

Comment: Ohh, yea, I mean the the cell text on 1st row..Now I get the point after your question, I can iterate the 1st row cell data and get the values..

Answer (score 1):

Excel columns don't have names. They only have letters, eg A, D, BB

To work out how to map an Excel-style column letter into a POI-style 0-based index, you need to use the method [convertColStringToIndex(java.lang.String ref)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html#convertColStringToIndex%28java.lang.String%29) which does it for you

If you mean you want to lookup a column based on the value held in the first row, you should do something like:

```
DataFormatter fmt = new DataFormatter();
Map<String,Integer> headings = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
Row headings = sheet.getRow(0);
if (headings == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty headings row");
for (Cell c : headings) {
    headings.put(fmt.formatCellValue(c), c.getColumnIndex());
}
```

If you have more complex use cases, such as a heading running over multiple rows, you'll need to write more complex code... It's all driven by your use-case